# PHP converting an Array into an object for woocommerce API

Tags: php, arrays, object, woocommerce

I need to format my data so that I can pass it to a woocommerce object.
I can create an array with this function.

```
function find_cat($object,$cats) {
    
    $found_cats = array();
    $count = 0;
    $found = false;
    
    foreach($object AS $catKey=>$catVal) {
       
        $new_array = (array)$catVal;
        
        $cat_name = $new_array['name'];
       
        if( in_array($cat_name,$cats) ) {
            
            $found = true;
            array_push($found_cats, array('id'=>$new_array['id']));
            
            $count++;
             
        }

    }
    if($found) {

        return $found_cats;
    }
    else {

        return false;
    }
}
```

The $categories comes from a API request.

`$cats = find_cat($categories, array($row['style'],$row['city'],$row['state']));`

Here is what I get when I print_r the array.

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 40 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 39 ) )`

Here is the code I need to send to WC

```
$data = [
    'name' => 'Premium Quality',
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => '21.99',
    'description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.',
    'short_description' => 'Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.',
    'categories' => [
        [
            'id' => 9
        ],
        [
            'id' => 14
        ]
    ],
    'images' => [
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
        ],
        [
            'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
        ]
    ]
];

print_r($woocommerce->post('products', $data));
```

I cannot figure out how to get my $cats array work in place of the WC code.

`'categories' => [ $cats ],`

Produces this

```
[categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 40
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 39
                        )

                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an array of array where it is not necessary :

```
'categories' => [ $cats ], // with the brackets syntax you are creating an array []
// but $cats seems to be already the array you need, so test with :
'categories' => $cats, // and tell me if it works. I think it will.
```